# Getting a number from KO observable

Tags: typescript

(I am sorry for so many Typescript questions - am just getting started with TS)

I have a KO observable called index.  I just want to increase the value of it by one.

Original JS code:

```
data.index(data.index()+1);
```

This gives compile error:  Left hand side must be a number... so I get the value as a number.

```
var currentIndex: number = data.index();
data.index(currentIndex-1);
```

However, I then get another compile error: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'number'.

How do I tell TS that index() is returning a number?

Comment: I'd assume it has no idea what `data.index()` is returning, so I'd suggest casting that value before incrementing... `data.index((<number>data.index())+1);` If that works I'll post as an answer

Comment: Yes, that works, will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A knockout observable containing a `number` can be defined like so:

```
var myObservable : KnockoutObservable<number>;
```

You should specify the type the observable will contain. For example:

```
var data = {
    index : ko.observable<number>(),
    // etc..
};
```

That way when you call `data.index()` the compiler knows the returned type is number:

```
data.index(data.index() + 1); // ok
```

Comment: Ah, generics to the rescue.

Answer (score 2):

it has no idea what `data.index()` is returning, so I'd suggest casting that value before incrementing...

```
data.index((<number>data.index())+1);
```

Or like your code above separating the code to two lines...

```
var index = <number>data.index();
data.index(index + 1);
```

Comment: This approach means that the casting has to be added *everywhere* where the observable is read/written to, which is a time sink, and if you forget to add it, the compiler will have a hard time checking that code. David Sherret's answer is much better because it only requires *one* type specification and no casts.

Comment: @DCoder I completely agree, I am not familiar with knockout, but was solving the issue presented in the question.